# MATLAB "Too many output arguments" error when calling a function using feval

Tags: function, matlab, return-value

I realize calling functions dynamically using [feval](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html) is inefficient but it's quite convenient in my application and works well, except in the case of one function.  I just can't see what is causing it.  The function works fine when called in the usual way but raises the error when called with feval (last line in below):

```matlab
x = 200;
[y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = lin_model_predict(model, x, vars, params);  % works fine

assert(round(y_mean, 4) == 139.7200);
assert(isequaln(y_sigma, nan));
assert(isequal(round(y_int, 4), [137.5938  141.8462]));

% Test again using feval
f_name = "lin_model_predict";  % this will later be set programatically
[y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = feval(f_name, model, x, vars, params);  % raises error
```

I include the function code below for reference:

```matlab
function [y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = lin_model_predict(model, x, vars, ...
    params)
% [y_mean, y_sigma, x_int] = lin_model_predict(model, x, vars, params)
% Make predictions with a linear model of the form:
%
%   power = a + b * load 
%

    % Make predictions using model
    [y_mean, y_int] = predict(model, x, 'Alpha', vars.significance);

    % TODO: Is there a need for sigma estimates?
    y_sigma = nan(size(x));

end
```

Full error message:

```
Error using classreg.regr/CompactPredictor/feval
Too many output arguments.

Error in test_lin_models (line 46)
[y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = feval(f_name, model, x, vars, params);
```

Matlab version: 2021b

**Update**

By replacing the last line with:

```matlab
a = feval(f_name, model, x, vars, params);
```

I figured out that it is expecting one output argument.

By debugging this call I figured out that it is calling a method of a class in CompactPredictor.m located here:

/Applications/MATLAB_R2021b.app/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+regr/CompactPredictor.m

From the docstring of this function:

```
        function yPred = feval(model,varargin)
%FEVAL Evaluate model as a function
%    YPRED = FEVAL(M,X1,X2,...Xp) computes an array YPRED of predicted
%    values from the regression model M using predictor values X1, X2, ...,
%    Xp, where P is the number of predictors in M.  Each X argument must be
%    the same size, and must have the same type as the corresponding
%    predictor variable. The size of the YPRED output is the same as the
%    common size of the X inputs.
```

And in this case the model argument is now the string `"lin_model_predict"` which  raises a new error `Unrecognized method, property, or field 'NumPredictors' for class 'string'.`

So it looks to me that the standard use of feval has been hijacked by this class method.

Not sure how to avoid this.  Any ideas?

I decided to post the question on the Mathworks forum because it may require expert input:

- [Multiple dispatch problem when trying to call the feval function with a LinearModel as an argument](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1918525-multiple-dispatch-problem-when-trying-to-call-the-feval-function-with-a-linearmodel-as-an-argument)

Feel free to add answers there or here.

Comment: Yes, that’s probably not the version of `feval` you want.  You can try typing `which feval` in your command window to further verify. Somehow this version got added to your path. Look into `rmpath` to remove it - or maybe just relaunch MATLAB.  You can also use `builtin` to call a particular version of a function but you shouldn’t have to do that here.

Comment: And, by the way, use of `feval` isn’t terrible (it’s not the same thing as `eval`), but you may find it slightly more efficient to specify the function name with a function handle rather than a character vector.

Comment: Thanks @horchler. `which feval` returns the correct version: `built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2021b.app/toolbox/matlab/lang/feval)`. But `which feval(f_name, model, x, vars, params)` returns `/Applications/MATLAB_R2021b.app/toolbox/stats/classreg/+classreg/+regr/CompactPredictor.m  % LinearModel method`.  I don't understand this since the first argument I am passing is a string, not the LinearModel.

Comment: Indeed, if you can use function handles, do that instead. I didn't think of that when I wrote the answer below.

Comment: Thanks but function handles is not an option because the function call is determined from a config text file.  I'd have to use a switch statement just to build all the handles. The answer you gave below using the builtin command is excellent and works—I just tested it. The much better way to do this would be to use classes and class methods but I wanted to avoid that level of sophistication due to the client and thought this would be simpler!

Comment: I just updated my answer, showing how you'd use function handles. You can use a dictionary to translate strings into function handles.

Comment: Still, I'm curious why `feval("my_func_name", model, ...)` calls a function with the signature `yPred = feval(model, varargin)`.

Comment: If a function `feval` exists that is explicitly overloaded for the class of *any* of the input arguments, then that overload is called. MATLAB doesn't look at the number of arguments to decide which function to call, only at the types of the input arguments you give when you call it. If there are multiple such functions (an overload for parameter #1, one for #2, etc) then it picks the one for the leftmost of these arguments.

Comment: That said, `varargin` matches any number of arguments, which will be collected in a cell array.

Answer (score 2):

In your line

```matlab
[y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = feval(f_name, model, x, vars, params);
```

one of the arguments is of class `CompactPredictor` (maybe `model`?), which triggers the overloaded version of `feval` to be called. This is how MATLAB does overload resolution.

There are several ways around this. One is to not use objects of this class, maybe by writing `lin_model_predict` to take a single cell array as input, so that you'd call it with `lin_model_predict({model, x, vars, params})`. Another is to use `builtin`:

```matlab
[y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = builtin('feval', f_name, model, x, vars, params);
```

A third solution is to not use `feval`. Instead, you could write a function that calls the right function for you:

```matlab
function [y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = my_feval(function_name, varargin)
switch function_name
  case 'lin_model_predict':
    [y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = lin_model_predict(varargin{:});
  case 'other_function':
    [y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = other_function(varargin{:});
  otherwise:
    error(['Unknown function ', function_name])
end
```

---

As [user horchler wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560803/matlab-too-many-output-arguments-error-when-calling-a-function-using-feval/75561201?noredirect=1#comment133311655_75560803), function handles are a much cleaner way to reference a function than through strings. With a function handle you'd do:

```matlab
f_handle = @lin_model_predict; % instead of f_name = "lin_model_predict";
[y_mean, y_sigma, y_int] = f_handle(model, x, vars, params);
```

But there are situations where only a string makes sense: Maybe the function being referenced is a private function and you don't want the caller to have direct access to them. Or maybe the string comes from a pull-down menu in a GUI or a configuration file. In these cases you can use a table lookup to translate the string into a function handle, see [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html) or, since R2022b, [`dictionary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.html).

Comment: These are great thanks. The most convenient for me I think is that `builtin` call.  Didn't know about that.

Comment: Function handles are not an option for me. Even though I wrote the statement `f_name = "lin_model_predict"` in the code in the question, in fact this name string comes from a Yaml config text file and therefore may have any of an arbitrarily large set of values. As far as I know `feval` is the only way to call a function with only its name.

Comment: @Bill If you don't have a complete list of functions that can be chosen, then `feval` is your only option. Of course you could use `eval` as well, but that is really bad and should be avoided if possible.